# Lister for watchOS 2 crashes on device

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

I'd like to build Apple's sample code "Lister" on device, but I couldn't build "Lister Watch App" scheme (not the old "Lister WatchKit App").

[Lister (for watchOS, iOS, and OS X)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1fe5d08c <+0>: trap   
    0x1fe5d090 <+4>: nop    


dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ListerKit.framework/ListerKit
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E0310855-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-77BBEE00D1DD/com.myname.app.Lister.nativewatchkitapp.app/PlugIns/Lister Watch Extension.appex/Lister Watch Extension
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E0310855-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-77BBEE00D1DD/com.myname.app.Lister.nativewatchkitapp.app/PlugIns/Lister Watch Extension.appex/Frameworks/ListerKit.framework/ListerKit: mmap() error 1 at address=0x001E4000, size=0x00018000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E0310855-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-77BBEE00D1DD/com.myname.app.Lister.nativewatchkitapp.app/PlugIns/Lister Watch Extension.appex/Frameworks/ListerKit.framework/ListerKit
(lldb)
```

Does someone successfully build Lister on Apple Watch?

Note: Turning on `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` didn't work.

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode7, iOS9, watchOS 2 all are beta 4, latest for now.

Comment: I have the same problem with including a framework inside a WatchKit Extension for watchOS 2. Seems to be a bug, so I'm reporting it.